# atomically removing the first line of a file AND returning it

Tags: bash, file, locking, atomic

I want to use a plaintext file as a task queue for my application (for writing to a database, though that's irrelevant), where:

1. I add an item to the queue via `echo "some task" >> task_queue.txt`
2. I remove an item from the queue atomically

For 2. I don't know a way to avoid race conditions if I am accessing/modifying `task_queue.txt` in multiple threads or processes. The following is not atomic:

```
ITEM=`head -1 task_queue.txt`
sed -i '1d' task_queue.txt
# process the item in the application
```

Does Bash provide a more elegant way to do this than using a lock file? I've never used `flock` before so I don't know if that's messy (e.g. when my application's task processing fails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I cannot confirm it's atomic, this is a lot more atomic than anything I can write myself (probably) and is good enough for my non-mission-critical app:

```
sed -i -e '1 w /dev/stdout' -e '1d' task_queue.txt
```

(credits: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108479/7000)

Answer (score 1):

All of these suffer from race condition, between checking if the file is being accessed, and doing operation on the file. Although presumably the time between checking and operation would be very small.

---

One way could be to use `pgrep` with the `-f` option to match full command line, and match if the file is matched i.e. if any process accessing that file. This assumes the process is not modifying it's command line.

This can do:

```
if ! pgrep -f task_queue.txt &>/dev/null; then
    ## File not Open, do stuff
else
    ## File is Open, do stuff
fi
```

Another approach would include parsing `lsof` or `fuser` (this is same as parsing `/proc/PID/fd/*`):

```
if ! lsof /path/to/task_queue.txt &>/dev/null; then
    ## File not Open, do stuff
else
    ## File is Open, do stuff
fi
```

Similarly `fuser`:

```
if ! fuser /path/to/task_queue.txt &>/dev/null; then
    ## File not Open, do stuff
else
    ## File is Open, do stuff
fi
```

Note that, here we are sending both STDOUT, and STDERR of `lsof`/`fuser` to `/dev/null`, this might not always be desirable as there might be some warning/error, and as we are depending on only the exit status, all of those will be mistreated as file is in use. This would be easier to implement if `lsof`/`fuser` has different exit status for different events, but all i can see is `1` for every kind of failure or no match.

Comment: Interesting approach, and I didn't know about `pgrep -f`. I wonder if this is better than using flock. I guess I'll have to pursue both options simultaneously and see which one I feel more confident about.

Comment: Hmmmm, actually isn't it possible that the "stuff" in the `if` body doesn't hold onto the file descriptor the entire time? 2 commands may have a small period in between which the file is not open, which may allow another process to steal it.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat There's obviously a possibility of race condition between `pgrep`, and operation on file, whatever small may be. If you want precision, you should look at locking mechanism e.g. `flock`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Though after `pgrep` is not my biggest concern. The bigger concern is my multiple commands that come after it. But I appreciate the suggestions and code samples.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Then you can (possibly) use a `while` construct, and run a single command at a time (if possible).